# FreeBSD: How do you use auditd for logging when files and folders are opened, read, moved, deleted or modified?

Tags: freebsd, linux-audit, freenas, auditdistd

How do you use `auditd` for logging when files and folders are opened, read, moved, deleted or modified? Looking at the information [here](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/audit-config.html), i don't see how to accomplish the task.

I'm trying to get a log of folder and file access/modification on a FreeBSD system. File access is via Samba share and i'm logging via SMB but in some rare instances SMB doesn't log a event (like today when a folder was moved, it wasn't logged but I moved a folder later and it was logged). Because of that, i'm looking for a more accurate alternative.

**UPDATE**
Here is what is not working with `auditd` on a FreeNAS 11 FreeBSD system.

Check the options kernel was compiled with (looking for AUDIT):

```
sysctl kern.conftxt | grep AUDIT
> options   AUDIT
```

My `/etc/security/audit_control`

```
#
# $FreeBSD$
#
dir:/var/audit
dist:off
flags:lo,aa,fr,fw,cl,fa,fc,fd
minfree:5
naflags:lo,aa
policy:cnt,argv
filesz:2M
expire-after:10M
```

My `/etc/security/audit_user`:

```
#
# $FreeBSD$
#
testuser:lo,aa,fr,fw,cl,fa,fc,fd:no
root:lo:no
```

`service auditd restart && service auditd status` results:

```
Trigger sent.
Starting auditd.
auditd is running as pid 45763.
```

Based on the `man audit_user` pages

> The flags field sets the system-wide default preselection mask for
>   attributable events. In the example above, successful and failed
>   login/logout events as well as authentication and authorization are
>   audited for all users.

I should at least be getting login/logout logs for testuser and root. And because of:

> Per-user and global audit preselection configuration are evaluated at
>        time of login, so users must log out and back in again for audit changes
>        relating to preselection to take effect.

I then logged out and back in as testuser via ssh, created some directories and files, and deleted them. I did the same thing via a SMB share and then logged in as root to check trail.

`praudit /var/audit/current` results:

```
header,56,11,audit startup,0,Fri May 24 09:50:23 2019, + 398 msec
text,auditd::Audit startup
return,success,0
trailer,56
```

Checking all available trails with `praudit /var/audit/*`:

```
header,56,11,audit startup,0,Wed May 22 14:41:33 2019, + 781 msec
text,auditd::Audit startup
return,success,0
trailer,56
header,56,11,audit startup,0,Thu May 23 18:44:10 2019, + 766 msec
text,auditd::Audit startup
return,success,0
trailer,56
header,56,11,audit startup,0,Thu May 23 18:54:51 2019, + 31 msec
text,auditd::Audit startup
return,success,0
trailer,56
header,56,11,audit startup,0,Thu May 23 18:55:04 2019, + 451 msec
text,auditd::Audit startup
return,success,0
trailer,56
header,56,11,audit startup,0,Thu May 23 18:55:04 2019, + 451 msec
text,auditd::Audit startup
return,success,0
trailer,56
```

I don't see any logs.

Comment: Add `audit_user` as well just to be sure, as it may override with `^fc,^fa` etc. I doubt that is the issue but it gives a complete picture (unless everything else for sure is default)

Comment: Tested `flags:fr,fw,cl,fa,fc,fd` on otherwise default audit settings. I get plenty of events. **NOTE:** It does not work in the same login session as root. With the settings applied I logged in as a regular user and saw the entries right away.
Auditd is very flexible and you can even set audit logging for specific processes using [setaudit](https://www.freshports.org/security/setaudit)

Comment: @ClausAndersen I updated my attempt to include info for checking kernel compile options, flags for audit_user, and test results. Did you do your test on a FreeNAS 11 system or a FreeBSD 11 default?

Comment: All looks correct to me. I am on plain FreedBSD. My test was on 11.2. I am left with the typical basic suggestions: Spin up a VM and test with vanilla FreeBSD. Then a VM with vanilla FreeNAS.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions in [16.3. Audit Configuration](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/audit-config.html) are actually very clear and to the point. You ask a question without even explaining what you have tried and what you learned from that. But let us try to walk you through the steps. In general terms you simply need to start the service (as any other). Examine the output. Then make suitable changes.

Start by following the section on how to start the audit subsystem:

```
sysrc auditd_enable=YES
```

And start the service:

```
service auditd start
```

As simple as that! You now have auditing running on your system. Now let us have a look at [16.3.2.1. The audit_control File](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/audit-config.html):

```
dir:/var/audit
dist:off
flags:lo,aa
minfree:5
naflags:lo,aa
policy:cnt,argv
filesz:2M
expire-after:10M
```

Take note of `dir` and `flags`. First look at the directory `/var/audit` specified in `dir`. You will notice 2 new files after `auditd` is started. An active log file named by date and `.not_terminated` and a link named `current`. This is then where your logs are stored. If you browse the files you will notice they are in a binary format. Then we cheat and look at the next chapter: [16.4. Working with Audit Trails](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/audit-administration.html). This reveals that we use `praudit` to get plaintext. Log into the system again and notice how this is logged using:

```
praudit /var/audit/current
```

It will look something like this:

```
header,56,11,audit startup,0,Thu May 23 16:18:46 2019, + 609 msec
text,auditd::Audit startup
return,success,0
trailer,56
header,97,11,OpenSSH login,0,Thu May 23 16:21:03 2019, + 443 msec
subject_ex,clan,clan,clan,clan,clan,82938,82938,57698,212.60.115.22
text,successful login clan
return,success,0
trailer,97
header,92,11,logout - local,0,Thu May 23 16:21:15 2019, + 90 msec
subject_ex,clan,clan,clan,clan,clan,82938,82938,57698,212.60.115.22
text,sshd logout clan
return,success,0
trailer,92
```

First we see the startup of auditd. Then you see me log in. And then log out.

Now we have confirmed that we can start an use the auditing system. We can then proceed and look at your specific requirements. You ask for:

> opened, read, moved, deleted or modified

We then look at the table in [16.3.1. Event Selection Expressions](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/audit-config.html) and find the most relevant:

```
fr  file read   Audit events in which data is read or files are opened for reading.
fw  file write  Audit events in which data is written or files are written or modified.
cl  file close  Audit calls to the close system call.
```

And maybe you have an interest in:

```
fa  file attribute access   Audit the access of object attributes such as stat(1) and pathconf(2).
fc  file create Audit events where a file is created as a result.
fd  file delete Audit events where file deletion occurs.
```

With this knowledge we can now set the `flags` in `/etc/security/audit_control`:

```
flags:fr,fw,cl,fa,fc,fd
```

Or if you want to keep the defaults as well:

```
flags:lo,aa,fr,fw,cl,fa,fc,fd
```

And if you do not feel you get all you want - then use `all` to examine what event classes you need:

```
flags:all
```

Restart `auditd` to make the changes take effect:

```
service auditd restart
```

So far this has been system wide. If you want to limit the auditing for only specific users you can then move on to `/etc/security/audit_user`:

```
sambauser:fr,fw,cl,fa,fc,fd:no
```

You can even fine tune this further and specify if you only want successful or failed events.

#### Remember man

Remember that FreeBSD is usually fairly well-documented. Apart from the FreeBSD Handbook (which you already reference) you have a fantastic tool in `man`:

```
man auditd
man audit_config
man praudit
```

The man pages are up-to-date and contains a lot of valuable and readily available information on the system. If you prefer you can browser [online](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is not working. Maybe FreeNAS 11 on FreeBSD changes how FreeBSD works, i don't know. i'll update original post with current settings.

Comment: Check if your kernel is compiled with `options AUDIT`. The GENERIC FreeBSD kernel is as default. FreeNAS use different setting - but it looks like [audit normally is enabled](https://github.com/freenas/build/blob/freenas/11.2-stable/build/profiles/fn_head/kernel/FREENAS.amd64)